# Dialogflow api suddenly returning CORS error

Tags: api, cors, artificial-intelligence, dialogflow-es, webhooks

Hi I have chat bot on my site which is suddenly returning CORS error i'm using JavaScript SDK of dialogflow

Comment: Same here. It returns 502 on each call.

Comment: yes same, for last 5 hours

Comment: so, what should we do, any suggestion please.. although same chatbot running in Mozilla and chrome with disabled CORS security, perfectly